# Forwarding of Docker Container running GUI on a non-GUI host

Tags: user-interface, docker, docker-swarm

I have a small cluster with docker nodes, I access it via a gateway server that I ssh into. What I would like to do, is to run e.g. Eclipse with a GUI on the cluster and access that GUI on my computer.

What I have found so far is this: http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/

However, the problem I'm experiencing is that the host computer doesn't run any x-server, since it's only a node in a cluster, so I cannot mount the required directory into the container.

Is there a way to use GUI applications in a container with this setup?

Comment: Did you try the OPs `ssh -X` way from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281992/alternatives-to-ssh-x11-forwarding-for-docker-containers?

Comment: I did now, but I'm having problems with the "trivial steps" that OP left out, but will report back if things work out. I'm currently trying to set up sshd using https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/using_supervisord/

Comment: Okay, it works perfectly for simply running a firefox :) Can I somehow give you credit for helping me? I didn't find that question using the search function, because I had another approach in mind, but this works well, thanks!

Comment: A thank you is cool :) Make sure to fill out an answer that solved your problem so others can do the same! You may mark it as accepted after 3 days. I'm interested in trying that later, too.