# Using X11-forwarding for Docker containers

Tags: r, user-interface, docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I am trying to build a Dockerfile which contains an Rscript through Docker run. I am facing an error related to tcl/tk package loading while building it for which I want to use X-11 forwarding and Display variable while building the docker file. I am currently following  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281992/alternatives-to-ssh-x11-forwarding-for-docker-containers). The problem that I am facing is that I cannot find **tmp/.X11-unix** directory in my machine as mentioned in the post. Is there any alternative for this for building docker file and to overcome the errors in tcl/tk package?

Comment: you mean /tmp/.X11-unix, right?

Comment: @user2915097 yes. cannot find it. could you guide where this file resides?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @user2915097 i am running linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ran the docker with the following statements and it solved the solution. 
The tcl/tk library needs a GUI to load itself so you need to set up an environment.

```
docker run -ti --rm \
   -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
   -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
  44589772e33b
```