# Display host computer with Tkinter From a python app run on Docker

Tags: python, docker, tkinter

**Context:** I am trying to build a pipeline. This pipeline consist in 2 phases, the first one is running a tool called DeCoSTAR (it's an executable, a binary) on a bunch of input parameter files. The next part is running a python app over the output files of DeCoSTAR.

What I want is for this pipeline to be user-friendly and portable, so it should run on whatever OS the host user has.

In order to do so, I am trying to use Docker.

Now for the first phase, I created my own Dockerfile based on a `python-alpine` image :

```
FROM    python:2.7-alpine3.7

MAINTAINER  *********

COPY    ./DeCoSTAR  /bin/DeCoSTAR

COPY ./DeCoSTAR.py      ./DeCoSTAR.py
```

`DeCoSTAR.py` is a way for me to launch the DeCoSTAR executable on a given 
parameter file (which will be on the host computer). In order for the user to provide this input I use Tkinter :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
#coding:utf8

from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import subprocess
from subprocess import call

def main ():

    print ("Input a parameter file:")
    Tk().withdraw() 
    param_file=askopenfilename()
    f= "/bin/DeCoSTAR parameter.file="+param_file    

    subprocess.call(f, shell=True)                       


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Now the thing is :

1. I can't figure out how to run DeCoSTAR.py automatically
   When I run my image it runs on python2.7. I've tried `RUN DeCoSTAR.py` but it doesn't work.
2. I use the `exec` command in Docker to try if would work either way.
   I've launched `python DeCoSTAR.py` and got this :

   tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

What I want is to display the open file window in the host computer so that the user can pick up and provide his own parameter file. I don't want it to display the container file, which is why I think it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand why but my first line : Hi everybody ! has been deleted , so i apologize

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to run a python script in Docker is necessary to do it like this:

```
RUN python DeCoSTAR.py
```

Second, for your `$DISPLAY` error, you need first to specify a display to docker in order to use a GUI application. It usually can be done by adding

```
-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw
```

to `docker run`.

Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281992/alternatives-to-ssh-x11-forwarding-for-docker-containers) question can help you if you have problems configuring docker to use your GUI app.