# Run tkinter inside docker container and export canvas as img

Tags: python, docker, canvas, tkinter, export

I want to run python script that only generates image from tkinter canvas. The error I am having is

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0"
```

I have find some simmilar problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281992/alternatives-to-ssh-x11-forwarding-for-docker-containers) so my attempt is:

running test.py

```
import tkinter
import random

canvas = tkinter.Canvas()  # <-- error occurs here
canvas.pack()

x = random.randrange(380)
y = random.randrange(260)
canvas.create_text(x, y, text='PYTHON')
canvas.postscript(file="my_drawing.ps", colormode='color')
```

inside docker

```
docker run --rm 
-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY 
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix 
-v $PWD:/app 
python:3.5.2-alpine python /app/test.py
```

However I have xvfb on my machine and it's also inside container after docker add so I don't really understand how to run tkinter without touching env $DISPLAY

Does anybody experienced similar problem?

Thanks

Comment: docker doesnt do great with GUI stuff .... best case senario you solve your issue with black magic and hackery and have a super fragile container that only you can help trouble shoot ... at least thats my experience with it

Comment: This container will just execute code and save IMG from tkinter canvas. There isn't greater purpose for the container just to be fast. That's why I don't want install additional software inside container. Have you experienced with such a magic that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need a display server for tkinter so i dont think there is any other way than installing a x server on the container itself (i am not sure if it is possible)

Comment: As you see in docker script I am adding part of X server that handles display but still no luck.

Comment: The x server needs a display device you can give docker access to all divices with docker run ..... —unpriviledged but i wouldnt use it