# Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly

Tags: centos, wine

Hi I have install wine (version wine-3.0.2)on CentOS 7 to run my .vbs file. but while running it got the below errors.

```
*000f:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"MountMgr" failed to start: 2
000f:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"WineBus" failed to start: 2
0019:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0019:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
0019:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
0019:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
0019:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
0009:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0009:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.*
```

Could you please help me to fix this. I don't have much idea about it

Comment: "Use this tag for questions about developing software that interoperates with Wine, or developing Wine itself. Questions about *using* Wine belong elsewhere, possibly on Super User."

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `DISPLAY` variable.

Try setting it to `:0` (assuming your display is on screen 0), e.g.

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

If you don't have your X server running, you can install [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb).

See: [How to make Xvfb display visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12050021/55075)