# Puppeteer error missing X server or $DISPLAY inside the docker

Tags: docker, puppeteer

I'm trying to run puppeteer INSIDE docker

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-bullseye-slim

RUN echo 'export PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD=true' > /etc/bash.bashrc

COPY . /project

WORKDIR /project

RUN apt update \
    && npm install --location=global npm -y \
    && npm install -g npm-check

RUN cd /project \
    && npm i

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install gnupg wget -y && \
    wget --quiet --output-document=- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-archive.gpg && \
    sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y --no-install-recommends && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

And this is my `docker-compose.yml` to create a container based on that image:

```
version: "3.9"
services: 
    accounts:
        image: holism/crawl
        container_name: crawl
        working_dir: /project
        ports: 
            - 3000:3000
        restart: always
        command: tail -f /dev/null
        volumes:
            - /project/package.json:/project/package.json
            - /project/app.js:/project/app.js
```

Then I go into the docker using docker exec -it crawl bash and I run node app.js. I get this error:

```
/project/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:262
                reject(new Error([
                       ^

Error: Failed to launch the browser process! undefined
[173:187:0927/084608.100277:ERROR:bus.cc(406)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[173:173:0927/084608.105774:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[173:173:0927/084608.105788:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting

    at ChildProcess.onClose (/project/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:262:24)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:529:35)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "puppeteer": "^19.7.3"
    }
}
```

and node version : v18.18.0

How can I connect it to my local machine's display?

Comment: Check this link (first answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68771874/run-puppeteer-headful-in-docker-container-when-the-docker-host-is-windows

Answer (score 0):

The Puppeteer documentation has a [guide to running](https://pptr.dev/guides/docker) a specific file where there is a browser launch using Puppeteer [the Dockerfile itself](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docker/Dockerfile)

In my Dockerfile, I inherited the developers' docker image and started my own project:

```
FROM ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer:latest

WORKDIR /home/pptruser

USER root
RUN apt-get update
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY src ./src
COPY index.ts .
COPY .env .
COPY fonts fonts/
COPY jest.config.ts .
COPY .prettierrc.json .

RUN npm ci
COPY .env ./dist/
COPY fonts ./dist/fonts/
RUN npm run build
COPY dist /app/dist
EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]
```

My puppeteer launch options for docker:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: ['--no-sandbox'],
      executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
    });
```

And the work is good. You can also use `headless: 'new'` instead of `headless: true` but that doesn't work for me. See also [troubleshooting](https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting)

Comment: That might work, but it's ill advised to run the browser without being sandboxed for security reasons.