# Is there a way to stream xvfb output?

Tags: streaming, robotframework, geckodriver, headless-browser, xvfb

I have automated robotframework tests that runs via xvfb on a jenkins agent, using firefox.
Sometimes I want to check what robot actually see for debugging.
I have found a solution to capture xvfb output as a video, but it would be great if I could watch xvfb output realtime remotely.
I don't like to use youtube or twitch services, my vision is **open the browser at something like `http://{jenkins_agent_ip}/xvfb` and see what the robot see**.
Is there a relatively cheap solution for that?

Comment: You should be able to do it with vnc, this answer should point you in right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050021/how-to-make-xvfb-display-visible

Comment: Thank you, good idea, I will give it a try!